# Execute callback when timer is started in C#

Tags: c#, timer

Is there a way to execute timer callback for the first time at the moment the timer is started (Using start() method), and not to wait for interval to pass for the first execution?

UPDATE: I'm using System.Timers.Timer.

Comment: Which type of timer (there are at least three)?

Comment: You can call the event handler yourself (it's just a method) immediately after you call Start(). Or just put the code in the event handler in its own method and call that in the timer elapsed event, and call that method just after calling start.

Comment: @Jon Probably the WinForms timer.

Comment: I can call it myself but then I must pass dummy sender and event args parameters. Can I trigger it somehow through timer object?

Answer (score 2):

A believe what you are looking for is described as dueTime here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, because the `Timer` is designed to call the event `Tick` **after** a certain interval it has started.

Instead, in your code you can manually call the event `Tick` when you first start the `Timer`.

P.S. I am talking about the WinForms Timer.

Comment: you can pass 0 to dueTime to start immediately as paszczi mentioned

Comment: @Bond I refer to the WinForms timer

Comment: @Bond There's System.Timers.Timer, System.Threading.Timer and System.Windows.Forms.Timer. Alvin is referring to the third.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd parameter (1000) is the due time as your wish:

```
_timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(InvokeTimerCallback), null, 1000, 3600000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a different timer, like [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx). This supports an initial delay (you want a 0) plus a period.